# launch uvicorn with external defined port

Tags: python, fastapi, uvicorn

I need to launch a microservice based on fastapi/uvicorn and running on a port defined in a config.ini file.
Here is my code

**config.ini**

```
[application]
version = 0.1.0
appName = kakarot
port  =  8001
description =  MicroService M1
```

**main.py**
`

```
from fastapi import FastAPI 
import configparser
# -------------- settings --------------------
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('configuration/config.ini')

APP_NAME =config['application']['version']
APP_VER = config['application']['appName']
APP_DESC =config['application']['description']
APP_PORT=config['application']['port']
# -------------------------------------------


@app.get("/someroute")
asyn def some_func(i : str):
  return value



if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run("main:app", host="127.0.0.1", port=APP_PORT, log_level="debug")
```

**server response**

```
INFO:     Started server process [9347]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:     127.0.0.1:44766 - "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
INFO:     127.0.0.1:43078 - "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
```

When i launch a "uvicorn main:app" ; the default 8000 port is used instead of the offline defined one .
What i am doing wrong ?
Many thanks

The documentation is not clear on that point

Answer (score 0):

How are you parsing the ini file, the vital content to judge what's going on is missing from your question. Have you checked the value of APP_PORT with a break point or print statement?

Compare your setup to the following working example;

```
import configparser

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('config.ini')

from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/")
async def root():
    return f"{config['application']['port']}"
```

Comment: Thank you .
I parse the config.ini with configparser just like you showed.
Here is the server's response :
"#8001"
but it is running on 8000 port !

Comment: So have you checked the value of APP_PORT with the __name__ == __main__ block?

Comment: Thanks ! it is resolved.
I tought that you've to launch via command line (uvicorn main:app) => but by doing it this is the default port used (8000)